# Pageble Kendo UI Angular 2 Grid with fixed height

Tags: css, angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I have enabled paging on the grid. I want the grid height to be fixed or 100%, and not "jumping" when browsing to the last page, which has less records.
The height declaration does not work with the pagable option, just with the scrollable option.

See
http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/GridComponent/#height-number

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The `height` option works when paging is enabled. See [this plunker snippet](http://plnkr.co/edit/ndOQzbBLgqNhlE7eMAyr?p=preview) for an example with both height and scrolling.

```
<kendo-grid
    [data]="gridView"
    [pageSize]="pageSize"
    [skip]="skip"
    [pageable]="true"
    [height]="360"
    (pageChange)="pageChange($event)">
</kendo-grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the height decleration does not work for me,
it is not "block" the height of the grid.
I tried to check the example you linked and its not working, error in running...

Comment: The example is slow to run, but should run eventually. The `height` property is used across the demo site, and can be seen in action. Regarding the grid not being `block`, this should be addressed in the latest kendo-theme-default package.